# how to merge multiple distinct queries to a single query to see output in multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Right now i have multiple distinct queries which gives respective results .. But i wanted to run a single query to get all those outputs in multiple rows..

Ex:

```
select count(distinct message_id)
from dssam.message_metadata
where object_id > 1177 AND workflow_type='3';   --- This gives o/p - 24

select count(distinct message_id)
from dssam.message_metadata
where object_id > 1177 AND workflow_type='4'; --- This gives o/p - 40

select count(distinct message_id)
from dssam.message_metadata
where object_id > 1177 AND flagged='true';--- This gives o/p - 6
```

But what i am looking for is .. o/p should be as below:

```
 [workflow_type  count
==============   ====
3                 24
4                 40
true               6][1]
```

Can somebody help me on this ..?

Comment: use Union All..with same column name......

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL` and a literal for the `workflow_type` column.

```
SELECT '3' workflow_type,
       count(DISTINCT message_id) count
       FROM dssam.message_metadata
       WHERE object_id > 1177
             AND workflow_type = '3'
UNION ALL
SELECT '4' workflow_type,
       count(DISTINCT message_id) count
       FROM dssam.message_metadata
       WHERE object_id > 1177
             AND workflow_type = '4'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'true' workflow_type,
       count(DISTINCT message_id) count
       FROM dssam.message_metadata
       WHERE object_id > 1177
             AND flagged = 'true';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid 3 scans of the table with some conditional aggregation:

```
WITH Aggs AS(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE mm.workflow_type WHEN 3 THEN message_id END) AS Workflow3,
           COUNT(DISTINCT CASE mm.workflow_type WHEN 4 THEN message_id END) AS Workflow4,
           COUNT(DISTINCT CASE mm.flagged WHEN 'true' THEN message_id END) AS FlaggedTrue
    FROM dssam.message_metadata mm
    WHERE [object_id] = 1177)
SELECT V.KPI,
       CASE V.KPI WHEN 'Workflow 3' THEN A.Workflow3
                  WHEN 'Workflow 4' THEN A.Workflow4
                  WHEN 'Flagged True' THEN A.FlaggedTrue
       END AS DistinctCount
FROM Aggs A
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('Workflow 3'),
                        ('Workflow 4'),
                        ('Flagged True')) V(KPI);
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter version of single scan + unpivot query.

```
WITH Aggs AS(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE mm.workflow_type WHEN 3 THEN message_id END) AS Workflow3,
           COUNT(DISTINCT CASE mm.workflow_type WHEN 4 THEN message_id END) AS Workflow4,
           COUNT(DISTINCT CASE mm.flagged WHEN 'true' THEN message_id END) AS FlaggedTrue
    FROM dssam.message_metadata mm
    WHERE [object_id] = 1177)
SELECT V.KPI, V.DistinctCount
FROM Aggs A
CROSS APPLY (VALUES('3', Workflow3),
                   ('4', Workflow4),
                   ('true', FlaggedTrue)
            ) V(KPI,DistinctCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the values in columns:

```
select count(distinct case when workflow_type = 3 then message_id end) as cnt_wt_3,
       count(distinct case when workflow_type = 4 then message_id end) as cnt_wt_4,
       count(distinct case when flag = 'true' then message_id end) as cnt_true      
from dssam.message_metadata m
where object_id > 1177 and
      ( workflow_type in (3, 4) or flag = 'true' );
```

(Note:  I assume that `workflow_type` is really an integer.)

You want them in separate columns so you can tell which row corresponds to which value.  Otherwise, you have no label on the row.  In a table called `message_metadata`, I am guessing that `message_id` is unique.

If this is the case, do not use `count(distinct)`.  I prefer `sum()` for this calculation:

```
select sum(case when workflow_type = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_wt_3,
       count(case when workflow_type = 4 then message_id else 0 end) as cnt_wt_4,
       count(case when flag = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_true      
from dssam.message_metadata m
where object_id > 1177 and
      ( workflow_type in (3, 4) or flag = 'true' );
```